# understand laravel dependency injection

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I would like to understand how automatic dependancy injection works in laravel. I am using this library https://github.com/yedincisenol/dynamic-links . It has a service provider class which binds to the IoC container

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('DynamicLinks', function ($app) {
        return new DynamicLinks($app['config']['dynamic-links']);
    });
}
```

And resolving the class gives me an instance of the library class,
`$dynamicLinks = resolve('DynamicLinks');`

As per documentaion, the class is auto injected if type hinted in the controller method,

> Alternatively, and importantly, you may simply "type-hint" the
>   dependency in the constructor of a class that is resolved by the
>   container, including controllers, event listeners, queue jobs,
>   middleware, and more. In practice, this is how most of your objects
>   should be resolved by the container.

this is my controller method:

```
public function getLink(Request $request, DynamicLinks $dynamicLinks) {
    // other stuffs
}
```

But the problem is, its not getting the configuaration file in the injected instance and throwing `ConfigException` from the library.
This is the constructor for the class

```
public function __construct(array $config = null)
    {
        if ($config == null) {
            $config = require_once 'config.php';
        }

        if ($config == null || !isset($config['api_key']) || strlen($config['api_key']) < 1) {
            throw new ConfigException;
        }

        $this->config   = $config;
        $this->client   =   new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=' . $config['api_key']
        ]);
    }
```

It seems that the class is being instanciated without the config instead of using the instance registered by the provider.

Comment: or the configuration is returning `null` ... also what does your class reference `DynamicLinks` point to in your controller method?

Comment: @lagbox, the class reference is the `yedincisenol\DynamicLinks\DynamicLinks;` class in the library. Thats why `$config` is `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the singleton is named `'DynamicLinks'`, which resolves to
`DynamicLinks`

And the controller method uses the class `DynamicLinks`, which resolves to
`yedincisenol\DynamicLinks\DynamicLinks`

In other words, when you expect it as argument in the controller, the service container tries to find `yedincisenol\DynamicLinks\DynamicLinks`, and because it is not registered as a singleton, it just tries to make to construct a `new` one.

-

Several solutions:

1)

Instead of having the class as controller argument, resolve it inside it as `resolve('DynamicLinks')`

2)

In the `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider`, in the register method, add:

```
$this->app->singleton(\yedincisenol\DynamicLinks\DynamicLinks::class, function ($app) {
    return resolve('DynamicLinks');
});
```

3)

fork or send a pull request to the package author to implement something along the lines of `2)`

-

So in a nutshell, i recommend going for option `2)`, which should ensure your controller will work as intended.

Comment: can also alias the binding to the FQCN

Comment: @lagbox true, but i forgot the exact syntax for it, so instead i shared code that i 100% know will work 

Comment: `$this->app->alias('DynamicLinks', DynamicLinks::class)`

Comment: @lagbox good to know, its present in the [code](https://github.com/illuminate/container/blob/master/Container.php#L472) but not on the [documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container) 

Comment: @Quezler, "In other words, when you expect it as argument in the controller, the service container tries to find yedincisenol\DynamicLinks\DynamicLinks, and because it is not registered as a singleton, it just tries to make to construct a new one." -- pardon me if I understand it wrong, but in the register method of the service provider for the library, it is registered as singleton.

Comment: @SayantanDas it is registed as the string `DynamicLinks`, and the controller typehints the class `DynamicLinks` (aka `DynamicLinks::class`) which returns the string `yedincisenol\DynamicLinks\DynamicLinks`, which is not bound to the service container, so laravel just tries to make one.

Comment: @SayantanDas i suggest you try @lagbox 's comment instead of my `2)`, achieves the same and looks cleaner

Comment: understood. Thanks a lot for your time. both of you.  :)